# Probability of choosing $x$ in a sample of $m$ choosen from the total of $n$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random

Sorry for being ambiguous but the question is that a class contains $25$ boys and $15$ girls.   What is the probability of choosing $5$ students at random and choosing $3$ boys?

So the $5$ students picking at random would be $1/8$ but how can I incorporate $3$ boys at the end?

Thanks

Comment: Not much connection with $1/8$. There are $\binom{40}{5}$ equally likely ways to choose $5$ people. How many ways are there to choose $3$ boys and $2$ girls?

Comment: I may be completely wrong. Please feel free to correct.

Answer (score 0):

How many ways can you select $3$ of $25$ boys and $2$ of $15$ girls, out of all the ways to select any $5$ of all $40$ students?